# Looking for code that will make certain columns read only

Tags: column

I have 4 date columns in a list that need to be read only after the record is created. Does any one have code to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following approach. You can define your own column based on DateTime column and [define a custom field control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679964.aspx#bk_custfieldtype). There you can use the control derived from the original control for the DateTime field and set the control mode to Display:

```
// Custom field class
public class SPFieldDateTimeReadOnly : SPFieldDateTime
    {
        public SPFieldDateTimeReadOnly(SPFieldCollection fields, string fieldName) : base(fields, fieldName)
        {

        }

        public SPFieldDateTimeReadOnly(SPFieldCollection fields, string typeName, string displayName) : base(fields, typeName, displayName)
        {

        }

        public override BaseFieldControl FieldRenderingControl
        {
            get { return new DateTimeFieldReadonly(); }
        }
    }

    // Custom field control class
    public class DateTimeFieldReadonly : DateTimeField
    {
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            // Here's all the magic
            ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;

            base.CreateChildControls();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add event receiver: OnItemUpdating end cancel properties updating.

```
public class MyEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
       public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           string myDateColumnName = "date1";
           properties.AfterProperties[myDateColumnName] =
           SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime((DateTime)properties.ListItem[myDateColumnName]);
       base.ItemUpdating(properties);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what BioGeneZ said, you can hide the the field to show up in editform, so users will never see the field to update

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://test"
$list = $web.Lists["listname"]
$fields = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("nameofcolumn")
$field.ShowInEditForm = $false
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Just adding to your post... I have used this as a "poor man's" approach to making the field read only, but this is not the way to go if there is a more than casual reason to require the field not be allowed to change. It also would not be able to address a potential issue where you might want to allow the field to be edited by members of certain groups.

Comment: You are absolutely right, as we are only hiding the field in as opposed to actually making it read-only.